# How to create a spiral logo or shape in adobe illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo

This shape was created using Adobe Illustrator.:

[image: spiral vector]

How can I recreate it?

Answer (score 4):

Spiral Tool

Draw a spiral, use Scissors Tool to cut, apply a Stroke Profile via the Stroke Panel or Control bar.

Copy, reduce, and rotate

repeat.

[image: spiral]